# How to Solve a Coupled Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the set of following coupled equations while studying cycloid motion in Griffiths' *Intro to ED*

$\ddot{y}=\omega \dot{z}$

$\ddot{z}=\omega (\frac{E}{B}-\dot{y})$

I am at a loss as to how I may approach the problem to solve. Any help is appreciated.